# caesar cipher brute force decryption

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, encryption

I am trying to write my own python code to brute force a caesar cipher and I need some help. I specifically need help near the end of my code of the function. I want to know how to print specifically so that after each key tried there is a gap. I am using python 3.3 and have just started coding 3 weeks ago.

```
print ("The plaintext will be stripped of any formatting such as spaces.")
freqlist = []
maxkey = 26
if key > maxkey:
    raise Exception("Enter a key between 0 and 26: ")
elif key < 0:
    raise Exception("Enter a key between 0 and 26: ")
freq = []
inpt=input("Please enter the cipher text:")
inpt = inpt.upper()
inpt = inpt.replace(" ", "")
inpt = inpt.replace(",", "")
inpt = inpt.replace(".", "")
for i in range(0,27):
       key = i

def decrypt():
    for i in range(0,27):
        for a in inpt:
            b=ord(a)
            b-= i
            if b > ord("Z"):
                b -= 26
            elif b < ord("A"):
                b+=26
            freqlist.append(b)
        for a in freqlist:
           d=chr(a)
           freq.append(d)
           freq="".join(freq)
           print(freq.lower(),"\n")
decrypt()
```

I am trying to use a for loop and I don't think it is really working effectively.

Comment: Sorry, by "working effectively" you mean is not working at all (and if so, with what error messages) or just not efficient? It might be a language issue, but I didn't understand that.

Comment: So now you have a frequency table of the input for every caesar cipher. What do you plan to do with these tables? How are you going to decide which cipher is correct?

Comment: I just need help and suggestions on how to improve this code.

Comment: Here is a error:   File "C:\Users\IshankParul\Desktop\module3.py", line 29, in decrypt
    freq.append(d)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'freq' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error you posted, I think this should help.

In Python, you can have local and global variables of the same name. The `freq` in the function is local, and thus the initialization of the global `freq` doesn't touch the local one. To use the global `freq`, you have to tell the function to do so, via the [global statement](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/ref/global.html). This is explained a little more in the [Python FAQs](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python).

That should be enough to get you back on track.

**EDIT:**
Below is an edit of your `decrypt` function, with some explanations of the changes

```
def decrypt():

    # we don't need the zero start value, that's the default
    # test all possible shifts
    for i in range(27):

        # initialize the array
        freqlist = []

        # shift all the letters in the input
        for a in inpt:
            b = ord(a)
            b -= i
            if b > ord("Z"):
                b -= 26
            elif b < ord("A"):
                b+=26
            freqlist.append(b)

        # now put the shifted letters back together
        shifted = ""
        for a in freqlist:
           d = chr(a)
           # append the shifted letter onto our output
           shifted += d

        # after we put the decrypted string back together, print it
        # note this is outside the letter loops, 
        # but still inside the possible shifts loop
        # thus printing all possible shifts for the given message
        print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me but i was also looking for something more which will also help me in my presenting my results.